# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error with IIS and ColdFusion

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, iis-7.5, coldfusion

I uninstalled ColdFusion 9 from my computer (windows 7/64 bit) but my `web.config` file, in C:\inetpub\wwwroot, still has the content below, which also includes info about ColdFusion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="JWildCardHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
            <add name="hbmxmlHandler" path="*.hbmxml" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="cfswfHandler" path="*.cfswf" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="cfrHandler" path="*.cfr" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="cfcHandler" path="*.cfc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="cfmlHandler" path="*.cfml" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="cfmHandler" path="*.cfm" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="jwsHandler" path="*.jws" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="jspHandler" path="*.jsp" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        </handlers>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.cfm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package zip" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now when I open 127.0.0.1 from my browser, I get

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error,
Handler:    Not yet determined
Error Code: 0x80070021
Config Error:   This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

Can anyone help me fix this error? I'm new to ColdFusion and IIS integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uninstalled ColdFusion, you can remove all of the child entries under handlers. You can also remove the mimeMap for .air. Change the defaultDocument value to whatever you intend on serving as your home page (index.htm, index.aspx, etc) This should eliminate the 500.19 error.